# Load shared library for another shared library

Tags: c, shared-libraries, dlopen

I am working on an update application that must be able to run on an existing system and is also started by another application on this existing system.

I am using a shared library that itself uses OpenSSL, but didn't link against it. Previously my update application linked against OpenSSL to work around this. But now I cannot link against OpenSSL any longer due to binary incompatibilities. Now when my application is started on the existing system, I get an `undefined symbol` error, because OpenSSL is not loaded. Note that I don't have the option to load it through `LD_PRELOAD`, because I cannot change the application that starts my update application.

I thought about loading OpenSSL through `dlopen` hoping that the shared library would be able to use it. But the shared library uses OpenSSL in a C constructor (`__attribute__((constructor (101))) void myConstructor()`) and even if I call `dlopen` inside another constructor with higher priority, the dynamic loader already seems to have searched (and failed) for OpenSSL. My constructor is not even being executed.

`LD_BIND_NOW` is not set, so I wonder why the `undefined symbol` error occurs before my constructor is being called.

Comment: To the one who downvoted my question: Please leave a comment at least, so I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself.

The problem was that shared libraries are initialised (i.e. C constructors are being called) before the main application. You can see the order when you set the environment variable `LD_DEBUG=libs`. So I created a shared library myself. I linked this fix library after the buggy library (`-lbuggy -lfix`), because initialisation roughly (I don't really understand the rules.) takes place in reverse loading order.

Now I was able to load OpenSSL inside the C constructor of my fix library like this:

```
void *p = dlopen("libssl.so.1.0.0", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NODELETE);
if(p)
  dlclose(p);
```

The flag `RTLD_GLOBAL` assures that OpenSSL can also be used by other libraries.
The flag `RTLD_NODELETE` assures that the library is not unloaded on `dlclose`.

Note: When my update application runs on a newer system with OpenSSL 1.1 and a shared library that correctly links against OpenSSL, loading `libssl.so.1.0.0` will fail silently, because the old OpenSSL version is not present on this system (embedded system, need to save disk space). If OpenSSL 1.0 was still present, this could be a problem.